# How to hide file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to hide a file in c#. I know the file path and can create a FileInfo object.

How can I hide it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The previously accepted answer:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

will result in certain other attributes it may have being lost, so you should:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: But it can be seen whenever I changed the settings from windows to show hidden files..I want to hide in that way it cannot be seen even if we have enabled to show hidden files

Comment: @AditKothari that can be achieved by deleting the file.

Comment: With a bitwise 'OR' operation, this will always result in Hidden being on, correct? Not simply toggle it?

To toggle it, would you use bitwise AND?

Comment: @omJohn8372: NO! Bitwise AND will *clear all flags other than Hidden*. What you are looking for is Bitwise XOR (`^`).

Answer (score 33):

```
File.SetAttributes("pathToFile",FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(myFileName);
    f.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(somefile);                
fi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `FileInfo` hidden attributes might be somewhat useless if the user's
windows is set to display hidden files. It is more advisable to move
file to a new path especially where user don't really navigate to like
`C:\Program Files\Common Files` or any path you might feel your user
show lesser interest of visiting before you hide the file.