# How to make a "Read only" file?

Tags: c#, file, file-permissions, streamwriter

I'm using the C# `StreamWritier` class. Questions:

1. How can I make a file read-only, so that no one can delete or write to it?
2. How can I make a hidden file?

I'm creating the file like so:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.FileName = textBox1.Text;
        save.Filter = "Text File | *.rtf";


        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());
            writer.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        }

        writer.Dispose();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You can look at that post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398398/1252575
Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590446/set-file-permissions-in-c-sharp

Comment: @peer i dont accept ur editing cuz u modified my code and deleted one of my question.

Comment: @Nickon the user peer edited my question it has a second part also.

Comment: Ahh, ok;) didn't know that. If u want normally hide ur file, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199571/how-to-hide-file-in-c
But when u want make it invisible in your file system, try PInvoke:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setfileattributes
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0469eb4f-9ee0-425f-ae90-382f2902898f
By invisible in your file system I understand hiding like in SystemVolumeInformation folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hello you can try with this method

1

```
 public static void SetFileReadAccess(string FileName, bool SetReadOnly)
 {
      FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);

      // Set the IsReadOnly property.
      fInfo.IsReadOnly = SetReadOnly;

 }
```

2

```
File.SetAttributes(yourFilePath, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

......

Comment: Yakoub can you check the second part of my question please someone edited and deleted the second part so i re-edited. thanks. by the way i voted you all up.

Comment: Thank's Modest I added second answer

Comment: thanks i just indent ur code of the first anwer so that other people can read too. thanks. i accepted your answer.

Comment: I'am happy to answer you Modest, i'am sorry for indent

Answer (score 11):

You can set the ReadOnly attribute using [`File.SetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx).

Example:

```
File.SetAttributes(textBox1.Text, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Note that this only sets the readonly flag, it does not modify the NTFS access control lists (meaning that every skilled user can remove the read-only attribute). Note also that this resets all other attributes of the file, which should not be a problem in your case, since your are creating a new file anyway. If you need to keep existing attributes, use [`File.GetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx) first and combine the existing flags with your new one (see the example on the linked MSDN page).

---

If you need to *secure* the file against malicious write attemts, you *must* understand NTFS security (google for "NTFS security" for lots of resources). Once you understand that, the following question will tell you how to modify them in C#:

- [Setting NTFS permissions in C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451861/setting-ntfs-permissions-in-c-net)

Comment: how will i use it and make it? is it possible to show on my code?

Comment: yes thanks Heinzi i see. i replied to u before u edited your answer i think.

Comment: my question was edited by peer and he deleted my second part of the question so i re-edited do u have a say for the second question? thanks.

Comment: File.SetAttributes Method     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Use this for a Read Only file:

```
FileAttributes yourFile = File.GetAttributes(yourFilePath);
File.SetAttributes(yourFilePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Where "yourFilePath" is a string.

For a hidden file:

```
FileAttributes yourFile = File.GetAttributes(yourFilePath);
File.SetAttributes(yourFilePath, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

And for a normal file (not Read Only, nor Hidden):

```
FileAttributes yourFile = File.GetAttributes(yourFilePath);
File.SetAttributes(yourFilePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

I know you didn't ask for setting a normal file but I think it's useful to know this.

Comment: Rodrio can you check the second part of my question please someone edited and deleted the second part so i re-edited. thanks. by the way i voted you all up.

Comment: thanks a lot i think all your answers works and i voted you all up but i already accepted Aghilas Yakoub answer so don't misunderstand me. i really thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Same answer, but with one line of code:

```
// Hide and read-only in one line
File.SetAttributes(filePathFinal, FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line answer to question #1 (without changing other file attributes):

```
new FileInfo(filename).IsReadOnly = true;
```