# hide settings.xml file from a user but not a programmer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, settings, desktop

C# Windows Desktop Application

.Net 4.5

What is a best practice for get a programmer/admin/deployment ability to change settings.xml file BUT hide/prevent changing this file by a user?

Condition:
settings.xml is in the same folder as .exe file

I did a search at the forum. But what is the simplest solution?

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: If did understand your question, you'd want to set up a database for user accounts in your application.
You can't stop people from editing a local file but you can encrypt it for instance and make it so that only users with an admin role could access it.

Comment: Thank you Angelo, 
So, as a programmer/deployment package I would not have an admin role.

Comment: To be clear, an admin role is simply a type of user that you will manually assign to yourself or anyone else who should access the file. For example, you have your `user` class with a `type` property. By default the constructor will assign `type`, the attribute `regular`. But you can make an interface for instance to change an account type to `admin`.
Otherwise, you can always try to create a readOnly file, or even make it hidden. However, there might be ways to bypass it. So it's not entirely secure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777924/how-to-make-a-read-only-file