# How do I enable/disable the Hidden option for a file or folder?

Tags: c#

How can I use C# to enable or disable the Hidden option for a file or folder?

As an example, see the picture below. The Hidden option is disabled. How can I write code to have this effect?

[image: unhide files]

Comment: what have you tried ? What are you trying do develop ? a windows application ? a console application ? a web application ? a service ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199571/how-to-hide-file-in-c

Comment: Try over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199571/how-to-hide-file-in-c

Comment: As far as the edit, I *think* the OP wants to be able to *disable* the checkbox, not toggle the value.

Comment: @sircodesalot - you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

System folders and files have the Hidden checkbox disabled:

```
new FileInfo(file).Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System
```