# How to hide your files from user in C#

Tags: c#, file, hide

I designed an application which reads alphabets from text files placed in debug folder and displays them on dot matrix screen. I want to keep the Text files confidential, Is there any way to distribute my application while keeping the files and folder inside "bin" hidden. One way that i can think of is to encrypt the data , but it's not an efficient solution for me as there are around hundred files. Any kind of suggestion will be helpful 
Thanks !!

Comment: Well there's [How to hide file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1199571), but that really just hides them from the UI, the user can show hidden files if they want, see [How to toggle Show/Hide hidden files in Windows through command line?](https://superuser.com/q/1151844) or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files

Answer (score 0):

The approach would vary depending on the type of application (web, desktop, mobile, etc.). **Assuming this is a desktop application**...

You could [embed the resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8) then attempt to use an obfuscator (example [Redgate's SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/)) to increase the level of difficulty of decompiling your application o access the file(s). Some obfuscator tools (example [Crypto Obfuscator For .NET](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm)) allow for encryption signed with certificates to increase the level of security.

Note that embedding and obfuscating is not guaranteed but depending on your average user, and the importance of the files, it may be just enough.